# How to use proper punctuation in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

What are the proper punctuations to use in the sentence below? Or would it be better to just separate it into two sentences?

> What doing nothing can do is help you know what you really want; is it roses, or gladiolas, or redwoods, or none of those, so that you don’t end up with a beautiful garden of what you don’t want.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for (sorely needed! :) *writing advice*.

Comment: I like the two answers so far..  However, I think the basic premise is wrong.  You won't know what you really want until you experiment.  So commit and plant, just spread it over several years.

Answer (score 1):

For more formal writing the wording should be revised for clarity and ease of reading (I would replace "What doing nothing can do is" with "Doing nothing can" to begin with) but if we are not writing for a formal context we also have more freedom to use punctuation in a way sometimes frowned upon today, like mid-sentence question marks:

> What doing nothing can do is help you know what you really want: is it roses? or gladiolas? or redwoods? or none of those? so that you don't end up with a beautiful garden of what you don't want.

A second option, with dashes instead of a colon, commits the atrocity of a dash pulling away from a question mark:

> What doing nothing can do is help you know what you really want – is it roses? or gladiolas? or redwoods? or none of those? – so that you don't end up with a beautiful garden of what you don't want.